# convolution matrix filter size vs channel length

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am a beginner in computer vision. what I would like to know the relationship between the size of the filter and channel over the output image

My aim is to understand the various relation that connect the size and the channels with the Convolutional Neural Network

I am using tensorflow library , i have found an example that apply CNN on **cifar 10** data-set ,

data-set consists of :-

1. data -- a 10000x3072 numpy array of uint8s. Each row of the array
   stores a 32x32 colour image. The first 1024 entries contain the red
   channel values, the next 1024 the green, and the final 1024 the
   blue. The image is stored in row-major order, so that the first 32
   entries of the array are the red channel values of the first row of
   the image.
2. labels -- a list of 10000 numbers in the range 0-9.

The Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,32,32,3])
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,10])



hold_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

#  Helper Functions 



def init_weight(shape,name_W):
    init_rand_dist = tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(init_rand_dist,name=name_W)

#  init bais

def init_bias(shape, name_b):
    init_bias_vals = tf.constant(value=0.1,shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(init_bias_vals,name=name_b)

#  convolution 2d

# Conv2D

def conv2d(X,W,name_conv):
    #  X --> [batch,H,W,Channels]
    #  W --> [filter H , filter W , Channel In , Channel Out]



    return tf.nn.conv2d(X,W,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME',name=name_conv)

#  convolutional Layer with activation and bais

# Convolutional Layes

def convolutional_layer(input_x, shape,name_W,name_b,name_conv):
    W = init_weight(shape = shape,name_W=name_W)
    b = init_bias(shape = [shape[3]],name_b = name_b)


    return tf.nn.relu(conv2d(input_x,W, name_conv =name_conv) + b )

#  pooling layer

# Pooling
def max_pooling_2by2(X):
    #  X --> [batch,H,W,Channels]

    return tf.nn.max_pool(X,ksize=[1,2,2,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')

#  Fully connected Layer

#  Normal Layer (fully connected Layer)

def normal_full_layer(input_layer,size,name_W,name_b):

    input_size = int(input_layer.get_shape()[1])
    W = init_weight([input_size,size],name_W=name_W)
    b = init_bias([size],name_b=name_b)

    return tf.matmul(input_layer , W) + b

#  Create the Layers 



convo_1 = convolutional_layer( X , shape = [4,4,3,32] , name_W = "W_conv1" , name_b = "bias_Conv1" , name_conv = "Conv_1")
convo_1_pooling = max_pooling_2by2(convo_1)



convo_2 = convolutional_layer( convo_1_pooling, shape = [4,4,32,64] , name_W = "W_conv2" , name_b = "bias_Conv2" , name_conv = "Conv_2")
convo_2_pooling = max_pooling_2by2(convo_2)

# ** Now create a flattened layer  [-1,8 \* 8 \* 64] or [-1,4096] **

convo_2_flat = tf.reshape(convo_2_pooling,[-1,8*8*64])



full_layer_one = tf.nn.relu(normal_full_layer(convo_2_flat,1024,name_W="full_layer_W",name_b="full_layer_b"))



hold_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
full_one_dropot = tf.nn.dropout(full_layer_one,keep_prob=hold_prob)



y_pred = normal_full_layer(full_one_dropot,10,name_W = 'out_W',name_b='out_b' )

#    Loss Function 

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_true , logits= y_pred ))

#   Optimizer Adam Optimizer. 

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#  Graph Session

steps = 5000

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)


    print (tf.all_variables())



    for i in range (steps) :   
        batch_x , batch_y = ch.next_batch(100)
        # print(convo_2_flat.eval(feed_dict={X:batch_x, y_true:batch_y, hold_prob:1.0}).shape)


        sess.run(train,feed_dict={X:batch_x,y_true:batch_y,hold_prob:0.5})

        #  PRINT OUT A MESSAGE EVERY 100 STEPS
        if i%100 == 0:

            print('Currently on step {}'.format(i))
            print('Accuracy is:')
            #  Test the Train Model
            matches = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred,1),tf.argmax(y_true,1))

            acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(matches,tf.float32))

            print(sess.run(acc,feed_dict={X:training_images,y_true:training_labels,hold_prob:1.0}))
            print('\n')
```

i am wondering about the filter size for example the first convolutional layer has filter size (4 * 4) and channel (32) , i would like to know why this numbers are chosen and cascade over the next layers .

another example the last layer

```
tf.nn.relu(normal_full_layer(convo_2_flat,1024,name_W="full_layer_W",name_b="full_layer_b"))
```

it takes the output of the flatten layer and resized to 1024 , also what is the reason behind that

as this image also [image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry, if it is not clear . my question related to the size of the channel as in `convo_1 = convolutional_layer( X , shape = [4,4,3,32] , name_W = "W_conv1" , name_b = "bias_Conv1" , name_conv = "Conv_1")` . here the channel input is 3 which is the 3 color RGB , what is the reason behind choosing the number 32 as the  out filter channel

Comment: i will update the question . to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

The filter size is the size of the window over which the convolution will be performed. It affects the rest of the network by interacting with padding to determine what's the height and width of the output tensor from that layer.

The output channels is what it sounds like: the number of channels in the output for that layer. So your example layer which starts with 3 channels (r, g, b) and has 32 output channels will produce as output something which is like an image but has 32 numbers per pixel instead of 3.

The size of the filters and their number of output channels are important properties of convolutional neural networks, and are chosen to maximize accuracy. Different architectures (inception, resnet, vgg, etc) make different choices about what filters to use and how many channels.

Comment: Thanks for your respond 
This answer is good start.  Let me elaborate and correct me if am wrong 
The channel size i treated it as feature size as in normal ML classifiers and channel out is how much features i want to collect from the images